# How to solve $x^{17}\equiv 37$ in $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

I need to solve the equation $x^{17}\equiv 37$ in $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$.

I've looked into these topics ([the calculation of the primitive root is missing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781368/primitive-roots-used-to-work-out-x7-equiv-5-pmod-11?rq=1), 
[n is not prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250539/how-to-solve-x3-equiv-10-pmod990)) but couldn't derive a solution.

So summarize what I know:

1. 101 is prime $\implies \mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic group (or even a field)
2. since $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic it has a generator with the same order of $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$. In this case the generator has order $\phi(101)=101-1=100$
3. due to Fermat I have $x^{100}\equiv 1$ $mod(101)$
4. $\phi(101)=100=2^2\cdot 5^2$
5. I have tried in vain to orient myself to: [$n-th$ root at the bottom of the page](http://mathafou.free.fr/themes_en/kcongr.html)
6. I know that the (only) solution is $x=52$

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Solve $17n \equiv 1 \bmod 100$. Then compute $37^n \bmod 101$ using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: thanks. $17n\equiv 1$ $\text{mod 100} \implies n=53$. But how to calculate $37^{53} \text{ mod 101}$ by hand? Could you pls explain why your hint follows to the right result (which is indeed $x=52$)?

Comment: is there another way? For example by using the prime factorization of $100$?